# Frozen Octopus or fresh Octopus for recipes?

Tags: grilling, steaming, recipe-scaling, octopus

Yeah, I wonder with grilled, fried, steamed, salad recipe, which is better?

```
Frozen Octopus or fresh Octopus
```

Can you compare Frozen Octopus and fresh Octopus, which recipes for which?
Thank you so much, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I'd guess that where you are would highly change which one you'd use.

Answer (score 4):

[This is my favorite reference for octopus](http://www.nytimes.com/2008/03/05/dining/05curious.html).  Near the end, Harold McGee considers the fresh v. frozen octopus debate.  His results are not exactly conclusive. McGee found fresh octopus, lightly blanched, to be "sweetly scallop-like and not too chewy.  But cooking it turned it bouncier than ever." His conclusion: "Freshness isn't the key to relevatory octopus."  So, based on my reading, if your preparation only requires a light blanching and thin slices, go with fresh.  Otherwise, you are better off considering the cooking technique as the most important variable.

Answer (score 2):

After catching and cleaning them, I usually freeze them.

One day in the freezer is enough to break some of the tissues, which helps making it much softer.

Comment: I've heard that buying frozen is the secret to tender octopus, so I'm not surprised.